# MySQL Count Query with Join to filter query result by value in second table

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to query a table and use a join to filter the result. Table 1 is the table I'm counting from. This Query returns a result of 216

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  plate 
WHERE
plates.Status = 'Sent to Device' AND plates.PlateDeviceName = 'Magnus3' AND plates.PlateDeviceIn BETWEEN '2017-12-19 07:00:00' AND '2017-12-19 15:00:00'
```

I need to filter this by a second related table `outputgroups` from the value in the field of `PlateType`. The tables `outputgroups` and plates are related with the fields `plates.OutputGroupID = outputgroups.OutputGroupID`. This query Is what I think I should be using but it returns a count of zero, 0.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  plates INNER JOIN outputgroups ON outputgroups.OutputGroupID = plates.OutputGroupID
WHERE
 outputgroups.PlateType = 'KBA' AND plates.status = 'Sent to Device' AND plates.PlateDeviceName = 'Magnus3' AND plates.PlateDeviceIn BETWEEN '2017-12-19 07:00:00' AND '2017-12-19 15:00:00'
```

It should also return 216 since all the plates made during that time frame are 'KBA' plates. I've tried numerous different variants of this query all with the same result of Zero. If I remove the Date/Time constraint I get results but I have no way to verify they are correct since the time span is over a year and the count is ~36K. I know I must be missing something in the JOIN syntax that I'm not understanding and could use some help.

Comment: if both return 216 - why filter? I would probably change the `count(*)` to a `*`  and the `inner join` to a `left join` and visually inspect the data - there must be some misalignment

Comment: Make sure they actually equal "KBA" in that outputgroups table.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the query. The only explanation is that the `PlateType` isn't actually `KBA`. What happens if you get rid of that part of the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query ... I would observe that you're counting free information- in the sense that the count is equal to the number of rows returned without the count.

Comment: Doh. The query does work. The the input name for the plates had been changed from 'KBA' to 'KBA Tr' which matches what Barmar suggested. Thanks for the comments. My problem at this point is solved.